# Load input to MySQL table via Python fails with bad column length

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to learn how to run MySQL through Python. This code does
nothing but open the database and try to load data into an empty table
in it.

```
import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.Connect(host='localhost', user='xx', passwd='xx',   db='xx')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/APath/aFile' INTO TABLE xx FIELDS TERMINATED   BY '\r\n'"
cursor.execute( query )
connection.commit()
```

It fails with this error:

```
 File "test0.py", line 7, in <module>
    cursor.execute( query )
  File
 "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py",
 line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File
 "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py",
 line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'xkey'
 at row 1"
```

xkey would be the first column in the table, so it's failing
immediately. I'm assuming that my terminate instruction is bad, so how
do I see what it's trying to load into that column, so that I can fix
it? If I'm wrong about that, what should I be trying?

Comment: Sounds like the data you are trying to insert is greater than the column value specified. Can you tell us more about your DB schema?

Comment: Your command states that fields are terminated by `\r\n`. Are you sure that this is correct? If it is correct, what is the line terminator?

Comment: Haymaker:  I'm loading into a 64 column table: the first column is char[10] Here is some of its first row:  0009999000      9601 N XX RD      2516025 441050  5093    5093    5093   \
     \
  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0       0    \
   0                                                                           \
                            867300  996700  996700  908600  907100  905000  897\
300  891400  873100  1140000 1140000 1140000 0       0       0       0       0 \
      0       0       0       0       0       0       0

Comment: Richard St-Cyr: you're correct. the field terminator is \r. I corrected that, added the \n as a line terminator and ran again: it still finds the first column too long.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies: it seems that it really needs not FIELDS, but LINES TERMINATED BY '\r

However, I think that the field terminator is '\r', so I don't understand why leaving  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r', still generates the error even if I add the correct LINES terminator. It works if I leave only the LINES part.